# Regex recursive code block content

Tags: php, regex, recursion, laravel-blade

I require to get the content between 2 directives (`embed` and `endembed`) using RegEx. My current pattern does this correctly `/(?<!\w)(\s*)@embed(\s*\(.*\))([\w\W]*?)@endembed/g`.

However, when the directives are nested it does not matches the blocks correctly. https://regex101.com/r/nL8gV5/2,

```
@extends('layouts/default')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @embed('components/box')
                @section('title', 'Box title')
                @section('content')
                    <h4>Haai</h4>
                    Box content
                @stop
            @endembed
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @embed('components/box')
                @section('title', 'Box2 title')
                @section('content')

                    @embed('components/timeline')
                        @section('items')
                        @stop
                    @endembed

                @stop
            @endembed
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Desired output:

```
1:    
@section('title', 'Box title')
@section('content')
    <h4>Haai</h4>
    Box content
@stop

2:
@section('title', 'Box2 title')
@section('content')
    @embed('components/timeline')
        @section('items')
        @stop
    @endembed
@stop

3:
@section('items')
@stop
```

I've tried various patterns but i can't seem to get it right. It is in my understanding that i should use the `(R?)` recursive token combined with a backreference? something more like this https://regex101.com/r/nL8gV5/3. After spending several hours fiddling around, i still haven't got it working.

What am i doing wrong and what is the correct pattern?

Comment: sounds like it could be done much easier without regex, or say, using regex only to find the start and end tags. any reason why you want to do it all in regex?

Comment: as far as i understand, there is no a regex for nested parentheses. You can use more more complicated code, with successive replacing  parentheses to any char, while parentheses is still in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the outer `@embed` and nested ones, use [recursive regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html):

```
$pattern = '/@embed\s*\([^)]*\)((?>(?!@(?:end)?embed).|(?0))*)@endembed/s';
```

At `(?0)` the pattern is pasted. See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uN9xS7/1). Replace with captured `$1` while matching out:

```
$res = array();

while (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $out)) {
  $str = preg_replace($pattern, "$1", $str);
  $res = array_merge($res, $out[1]);
}
```

This will give you the outer and nested ones up to the innermost. [Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/410440)

---

The basic recursive pattern without any capturing is as simple [as this](https://regex101.com/r/bY1vA1/2):

```
/@embed\b(?>(?!@(?:end)?embed\b).|(?0))*@endembed/s
```

- Match the literal `@embed` followed by `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(?>` Using a non capturing [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) for alternation:
- Alternate between: `(?!@(?:end)?embed).` A character [that starts not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `@embed` or `@endembed`
  `|(?0)` OR paste the pattern from start. `)*` The whole thing any amount of times.
- Match the literal `@endembed`

Using `s (PCRE_DOTALL)` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for making the [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) also match newlines

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this recursive regex from an example I had (from this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23918617/5008284)):

```
(?=(@embed(?:(?>(?:(?!@embed|@endembed).)+)*|(?1))*@endembed))
```

Try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iE6lH6/1)